# how to calculate sum of column in a filtered table saved within a row (dynamic window / custom window)

Tags: python, pandas

**PROBLEM:** how to calculate sum of column in a filtered table saved within a row (dynamic window / custom window)

see below sample dataset:

**Desired output is column: SUM dynamic window**

```
d={'code':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],
   'price':[10,8,11,13,1.1,1.3,1.5,100,101,104],
   'group_index':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3],
   'index_start':[1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,1],
   'SUM dynamic window':[10,18,19,32,1.1,2.4,2.8,100,201,305]}

df_dynamic_window = (
   pd
    .DataFrame(data=d)
    .astype({'SUM dynamic window':'int32'})
)
```

[image]

I tried to filter table then apply sum. But unable to calculate it. filtered table is saved in a dataframe and Im unable to do aggregation on it.

```
df_dynamic_window['sum'] = (
     df_dynamic_window
       .apply(lambda df: df_dynamic_window
       .loc[
           Filter_Rows := (
               (df_dynamic_window['code']        == df['code']) & 
               (df_dynamic_window['group_index'] <= df['group_index']) & 
               (df_dynamic_window['group_index'] >= df['index_start']) ), 
           ['price']], 
       axis=1
       )
     )
df_dynamic_window['.sum()'] = df_dynamic_window['sum'].sum()

df_dynamic_window
```

[image]

Appreciate your help!